# <select> acting weird in this loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, loops

Think it might be best if I just show you the code.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($enheder)) {
echo"<tr>
<td>&nbsp;" .$row['Model'].
"<td>&nbsp;" .$row['SN'].
"<td>&nbsp;" .$row['Softwarever'].
"<td>&nbsp;" .$row['KobtDato'].
"<td>&nbsp;" .$row['Saelger'].
"<td>&nbsp;" .$row['ServiceDato'];

$dato = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Servicetxt WHERE Servicenum IN ($where);")
or die(mysql_error());

?><form>
<select name="dato"><?
while ($datorow = mysql_fetch_array($dato)) {
    if ($datorow['Servicenum'] == $row['ID1']) {
        ?>
        <option value="something">something</option>
        <?
    }
?></select>
</form><?

}

echo "<td>&nbsp;" .$row['CalDato'].
"<td>&nbsp;" .$row['KundeID'].
"<td>&nbsp;" .$row['ID1'].
"<td>&nbsp;" .$row['KundeRefNo'];


}
```

Sorry but I can't post screenshots apparently, I'll just have toexplain it. It acts weird if there is more than two options - instead of putting the options in the drop down, it just prints all the options right below an empty drop down. If there is only one option, it works perfectly fine. But why? This might be some simple silly mistake, but it's 05.46 in the morning here and I haven't slept for a long time now :D please help.

Comment: You're never closing your table cells.  Malformed tables tend to do very odd things.

Comment: Ok I've closed them now, didn't help. Thanks though.

Comment: Så gå i seng og se på det i morgen.

Comment: Paste what the rendered html looks like.

Comment: And you didn't close your table row

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893).

Comment: also dont use short tag its not a good practice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have not closed the if condition also not closing the table cells

`mysql` is deprecated use `mysqli` or `pdo`

```
<select name="dato"><?
while ($datorow = mysql_fetch_array($dato)) {
    if ($datorow['Servicenum'] == $row['ID1']) {
        ?>
        <option value="something">something</option>
        <?
    }// here was the mistake
}
?></select>
```

Comment: Thank you, works now. As I said silly mistake :D